# How to produce assembly output with Sublime Text?

Tags: c, assembly, sublimetext2

I've created a self defined build command when compiling `C` files in *Sublime Text 2* and it works OK.

The `output_c.sublime-build` file is as follows:

```
{
    "cmd": "gcc $file_base_name.c -g -O3 -m32 -std=c99 -fverbose-asm -fno-inline -save-temps -Wall -Werror -o $file_base_name.exe"
}
```

And then, I use the following `output_asm.sublime-build` command in order to create a more readable assembly file:

```
{
    "cmd": "objdump -d -M intel $file_base_name.o > $file_base_name.asm"
}
```

However, the second command (I mean, the second `output_asm.sublime-build` file) dumps the output on screen (just above the status line on Sublime Text screen) in stead of creating a `$file_base_name.asm` file.

Connected to the issue, I've two questions:

1. How can I format the **objdump** command, so that I can get the assembly output written into a text file?
2. How can I combine these two build commands in one `output_combined.sublime-build` file, so that the combined command file creates the `.exe` and the `.asm` file at once?

(System: Windows 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you questions:

1. if you use shell commands like `>` you must add `"shell": true` as argument (or in ST3 use `shell_cmd` instead of `cmd`)
2. if you use `cmd` in the shell, then you can just combine the two commands with `&&` (execute second command if first command was successful)

In addition I would recommend to add a scope `selector`, `working_dir` (especially when you work with `file_base_name`) and a `file_regex` (to click jump to errors). This results in the following build system:

```
{
    "cmd": "gcc $file_name -g -O3 -m32 -std=c99 -fverbose-asm -fno-inline -save-temps -Wall -Werror -o $file_base_name.exe && objdump -d -M intel $file_base_name.o > $file_base_name.asm",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "selector": "source.c"
}
```

Comment: Sounds fair but after giving a try, it spits out the following error: **`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shell_cmd'`** (link: http://i.imgur.com/0qENVO9.png)